# Loginview control: how to reference server side controls inside loggedintemplate

Tags: asp.net, loginview

In PageLoad event of the form, I can not reference server side control within logged in template. What am I missing. So when I am logged in I will show text box control otherwise I will show text like "please login to do soso.."

Please help ..

Comment: BTW.. this is for loginview control.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the FindControl method on your loginview control to get them...

```
TextBox t = (TextBox)LoginView2.FindControl("TextBox1");
string s = null;

if (t != null)
{
    // textbox is in the current scope of the LoginView
    s = t.text;
}
else
{
    // the textbox is not in the current scope of the LoginView.
}
```

However, this will only work for the controls that are currently in the shown view of the LoginView control.  You'd have to test that you're showing the logged in view before trying to grab the textbox, or you could also test that the FindControl doesn't return a null reference.

Comment: This is not working. I tried this...

        TextBox t = (TextBox)LoginView2.FindControl("TextBox1");

        string s = t.Text;


and this is the error I get...
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: you may have to go through a hierarchy of controls in order to get your textbox if it is nested in other controls. this is a horrible way to get access to controls because your access should be strongly-typed, not based on a string ("TextBox1"). I've looked up few methods to properly access these controls and it appears that there really isn't a good one, especially if there are a lot of them. if you want to deny your users access to pages when they're not logged in, have a look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815151

Answer (score -1):

If you're still having trouble referencing the hidden object, you might not be entering the right value for it. Say you have a drop down list called "DropDownList1" nested inside a loggedInView. You have to set a new object that uses the FindControl method of the DropDownList class, and then use that NEW object:

```
DropDownList d = (DropDownList)ucLogin.FindControl("DropDownList1");

       bool answer = d.SelectedValue.StartsWith("S");
       if (answer == true)
       {
           Response.Redirect("~/MemberPages/ChangePassword.aspx");
       }
```

In my case, I am redirecting the user to a new page if that objects selected value starts with an "S".

Works for me, and I hope it works for you!

- Ben sewards