# "Use the new keyword to create an object" instance error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a masterpage file which is called Masterpage.master which works fine with all my aspx pages except aspx pages in which I try to instantiate stuff in the Page_Load method in the codebehind file.

The aspx file called ManageRoles.aspx looks like this -

```
            <%@ Page Language="C#" 
            AutoEventWireup="true" 
            CodeBehind="ManageRoles.aspx.cs" 
            Inherits="eservice.ManageRoles"
             MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master"

            %>


            <asp:Content ID="Content2"  
                ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
                runat="server">
                <!-- Start of roles -->
                <h3>
                    Manage Roles</h3>


                <asp:Label ID="Msg" ForeColor="maroon" runat="server" />
                <br />

                <!-- End of roles -->
                <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView2" runat="server">


                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                         <p id="backtoblog"></p>



                <!-- End of roles -->

                    </LoggedInTemplate>

                    <AnonymousTemplate>

                    </AnonymousTemplate>


                    </asp:LoginView>

            </asp:Content>
```

and the  code-behind file called ManageRoles.aspx.cs looks like this -

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;
            using System.Web.UI;
            using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
            using System.Web.Security;



            namespace eservice
            {
                public partial class ManageRoles : System.Web.UI.Page
                {
                    private string[] rolesArray;
                    private string[] usersInRole;
                    MembershipUserCollection users;



                    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        // clear the Msg label on each visit
                        Msg.Text = string.Empty;


                    }

                }
            }
```

The Masterpage.master file contains a content section like this -

```
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

This is a web application project and it builds fine but throws a runtime exception when I click on the link for ManageRoles.aspx

I am getting the following exception -

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
  Source="eservice"
  StackTrace:
       at eservice.ManageRoles.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\das.arunabh\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ESERVICE_SOLUTION-MAIN\eservice\eservice\ManageRoles.aspx.cs:line 24
       at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:

Comment: Msg.Text = string.Empty;

Comment: Is there more code in Page_Load, especially statements using rolesArray?

Comment: The code using rolesArray is commented out so I can fix the issue above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `Msg` is a reserved word, but you might want to try renaming it. Most likely the designer didn't create the member variable properly in your Designer.cs file.  Try the following (basically, remove then readd the html for the label to get the designer to create the member variable):

1. Cut the html code out of the editor
2. Switch to the design view of the page
3. Switch to the code behind
4. Switch back to the page's designer view
5. Switch to source view
6. Re-Paste the code
7. Switch to the designer
8. Go back to your codebehind.
9. Save and if you're lucky, the code should work.

Comment: Hi Tim. I tried renaming and following the steps above but am still getting the same error. Please help.

Comment: Open your .designer.cs file.  Make 100% sure that the `Msg` variable is defined in there.

Comment: The designer.cs file contains the Msg variable - 
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Msg;

Would it help if I moved that declaration to the code-behind file?

Comment: No, and I don't know what else to tell you...  Sorry.

Comment: Solved this issue by creating a new MasterPage and placing the <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder> outside the <asp:LoginView></asp:LoginView> tags. Thanks for your help Tim!!

Comment: Also - I was able to find the control in my code-behind file as follows - 
    Label lblMessage = (Label)LoginView2.FindControl("Msg");
as illustrated here - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669551/loginview-control-how-to-reference-server-side-controls-inside-loggedintemplate

Comment: Ofcourse, I think the C# compiler is exceptionally dumb if I have to explicitly force it to find a control which is clearly in scope from the fact of it being on the same page as the code-behind file that it corresponds to.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would refrain from doing authentication services inside of masterpage code files...Use a login.aspx.cs Codefile for your actual authentication service and leave masterpage's to do what masterpages are meant for...Display Presentation and Content.

<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site" %>


  
  Forms Authentication, Authorization, and User Accounts

User Account Tutorials
    
        
        
      
      
    
     TODO: Menu will go here...

**Note: http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs**

Answer (score 0):

the error says you are trying to give a value to `Msg.Text`, but `Msg.Text` does not exist in your current scope.

Comment: Msg is the ID for the <asp:Label> that I have created in the aspx page so it should be in scope. Also, the designer.cs file contains the control - public partial class ManageRoles
                    {
                        /// Msg control.
                        /// <remarks>
                        /// Auto-generated field.
                        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
                        /// </remarks>
                        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Msg;
}